# How to remove all combination with the same element in subarray from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this array

`[[1,2,3],[4,1,6],[1,3,2],[1,2,4],[3,1,2],[4,6,1],[9,9,9]]`

and I want a function that do this:

`[[1,2,3],[4,1,6],[1,2,4],[9,9,9]]`.

This function removes all subarray with the same value.

I thought about a filter like this

`.filter(el => el.filter(value => array2.includes(value)))`

But I don't think it will work.

PS: I use node.js

EDIT: Weirdly, many of your answer work PERFECTLY with the example, but doesn't work in my true program... In fact I work with object instead of number. Like this: `[[obj,obj,obj],[obj,obj,obj],[obj,obj,obj]]`. But I don't know why it's work with number but not object...

EDIT2: I give now the minimal example, this object:

Note the actual array can have 20,000 items

```
  [
      [
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Cawotte',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Kaliptus',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ],
      [
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Emeraude',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Ocre',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ],
      [
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Kaliptus',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Cawotte',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          name: 'Dofus Cawotte',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Kaliptus',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }
      ]
  ]
```

should give this object:

```
  [
      [
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Cawotte',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Kaliptus',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ],
      [
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Emeraude',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Ocre',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ]
  ]
```

Comment: Your objects do not work because their toStrings will all be [object][object] and not "1,2,3". That shows the importance of giving a [mcve]. You may be able to use JSON.stringify instead of the sort

Comment: @mplungjan not really I posted the edit in my post.

Comment: Ignore it, the effect of the "dofus ocre" is always the same, I will delete this attribute to be clearly understandable

Comment: And from another comment "can have 20000 items". Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having aaray with objects and this objects have the same order of the keys, you could get each object as single [JSON](https://json.org/) string and sort the array of JSONs and join this strings to a single string and take this string as value for checking the uniqueness witn a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const
    normalize = v => v.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)).sort().join('|'),
    filterWithSet = s => v => (n => !s.has(n) && s.add(n))(normalize(v)),
    data = [[{ name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Cawotte', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Kaliptus', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }], [{ name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Emeraude', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Ocre', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }], [{ name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Kaliptus', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Cawotte', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }], [{ name: 'Dofus Cawotte', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofus Kaliptus', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }, { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 }]],
    unique = data.filter(filterWithSet(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: more like this: [[{a: "zaza", b:"zizi", c:"zozo"},{a: "zaza1", b:"zizi1", c:"zozo1"},{a: "zaza2", b:"zizi2", c:"zozo2"}],[{a: "zaza1", b:"zizi1", c:"zozo1"},{a: "zaza", b:"zizi", c:"zozo"},{a: "zaza2", b:"zizi2", c:"zozo2"}],[{a: "zaza", b:"zizi", c:"zozo"},{a: "zaza1", b:"zizi1", c:"zozo1"},{a: "sbeve2", b:"sbive2", c:"sbove2"}],[{a: "zaza", b:"zizi", c:"zozo"},{a: "sbeve2", b:"sbive2", c:"sbove2"},{a: "zaza1", b:"zizi1", c:"zozo1"}]]

Comment: does the properties of the objects always have the same order?

Comment: what order? of the objects in the outer array?

Comment: each sub array from the main array have this kind of object combination: `[
        { name: 'Dofawa', item_type: 'Dofus', level: 6 },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Cawotte',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Dofus Kaliptus',
          item_type: 'Dofus',
          level: 6
        }
      ] ` 
each object have the same amount of attaribute and the same order in term of attribute. Look at the example on the main post

Answer (score 2):

Technically it can be solved by creating a hash table where you add only the unique arrays into an empty `{}` object as keys. Unique value can be created by sorting the sub arrays first and adding as the key for the object. At the end, you can get out the values with `Object.values()` from your object.

Based on this idea I guess this can work for you:

```js
const array = [[1,2,3],[4,1,6],[1,3,2],[1,2,4],[3,1,2],[4,6,1],[9,9,9]];
const result = {};
array.forEach(a => {
  const t = Array.from(a).sort((a,b) => a - b);
  if (!result[t]) result[t] = a;
});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

From `Object.values()` documentation:

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please notice that your result is different than the one expected by OP

Comment: @mickl Right, `sort` did that! Just corrected, I have cloned with `Array.from()` the sub array which did the trick. Thanks, good catch!

Comment: Work perfectly with number but not work with my example, I forgot to add it. Now it's on the main post.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary using `Array.reduce` having sorted arrays as keys and then use `Object.values` to retrieve non-duplicated arrays:

```js
let input = [[1,2,3],[4,1,6],[1,3,2],[1,2,4],[3,1,2],[4,6,1],[9,9,9]]

let dict = input.reduce((state, current) => {
   let key = [...current].sort((a,b) => a - b).toString(); 
   if(!state[key]){
      state[key] = current;
   }
   
   return state;

}, {});

let result = Object.values(dict);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `reduce()` function and use `JSON.stringify()` to compare the current, sorted array to the arrays already added to the accumulator.

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,1,6],[1,3,2],[1,2,4],[3,1,2],[4,6,1],[9,9,9]];

const res = arr.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    let match = false;
    acc.forEach(el => {
       if(JSON.stringify(cur.concat().sort()) === JSON.stringify(el.concat().sort())){
          match = true;
       }
    });

    return match ? acc : acc.concat([cur]);
},[]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please note that your result is different than the one expected by OP

Comment: `el.sort()` is changing the original sub arrays in `arr` variable, same happened with me.

Comment: Your answer seem good, but with my true program it seem to be very heavy I wait more than 20 sec and nothing it continue to work, I work with an array of ~20000 elements...